# Access/SQL Interval breakout

Tags: sql, ms-access

**EDIT: SIMPLIED CODE**

```
CODE   START                    END                       TLY
X      7/12/2016 10:30:00 AM    7/12/2016 11:00:00 AM     68
X      8/14/2016 09:30:00 AM    8/14/2016 11:00:00 AM     11
```

I was looking for some assistance with an odd table that I have pulled into Access (using SQL to query).  The underlying issue I have is sometimes the data can be every 30 minutes as represented in line one (10:00-10:30) or it could be multiple intervals such as line two 09:30-11:00.

Ideally, I'd like to represent this as every 30 minute period they are reporting for so the data would look as follows:

```
CODE   START                    END                       TLY
X      7/12/2016 10:30:00 AM    7/12/2016 11:00:00 AM     68
X      8/14/2016 09:30:00 AM    8/14/2016 10:00:00 AM     11
X      8/14/2016 10:00:00 AM    8/14/2016 10:30:00 AM     11
X      8/14/2016 10:30:00 AM    8/14/2016 11:00:00 AM     11
```

Code used:

```
SELECT
 SGT.CODE AS CODE, CVDate((SGT.START_MOMENT-240)/1440) AS START, 
  CVDate((SGT.STOP_MOMENT-240)/1440) AS END, 
  SGT.TLY AS TLY
FROM
  STF_GRP_TLY AS SGT
```

Any thoughts or suggestions that I could try?

Thank you!

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside your joins and date/time math [... - 240)/1440] for the moment, if you have a data table

[tblIntervals]

```
CODE          START                END                  TLY
------------  -------------------  -------------------  ---
Group_Sample  2016-07-12 10:30:00  2016-07-12 11:00:00   68
Group_Sample  2016-08-14 09:30:00  2016-08-14 11:00:00   11
```

and you create a "numbers table" that starts with zero and counts up (by one) to more than the maximum number of half-hour subintervals you would ever expect to encounter, e.g.

[tblNumbers]

```
 n
--
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
```

then you can create a query that uses a cross-join to list the individual sub-intervals like so:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblIntervals.CODE,
    DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, tblIntervals.START) AS dtmSTART,
    DateAdd("n", 30 * (tblNumbers.n + 1), tblIntervals.START) AS dtmEND,
    tblIntervals.TLY
FROM
    tblIntervals, tblNumbers
WHERE
    DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, tblIntervals.START) < tblIntervals.END
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

returning

```
CODE          dtmSTART             dtmEND               TLY
------------  -------------------  -------------------  ---
Group_Sample  2016-07-12 10:30:00  2016-07-12 11:00:00   68
Group_Sample  2016-08-14 09:30:00  2016-08-14 10:00:00   11
Group_Sample  2016-08-14 10:00:00  2016-08-14 10:30:00   11
Group_Sample  2016-08-14 10:30:00  2016-08-14 11:00:00   11
```

**Edit**

To incorporate the conversion from "nominal" to "real" date/time values you could use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    STF_GRP_TLY.STF_GRP_SK, 
    DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, CDate((STF_GRP_TLY.START_MOMENT-240)/1440)) AS dtmSTART, 
    DateAdd("n", 30 * (tblNumbers.n + 1), CDate((STF_GRP_TLY.START_MOMENT-240)/1440)) AS dtmEND, 
    STF_GRP_TLY.TLY 
FROM STF_GRP_TLY, tblNumbers 
WHERE 
    DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, CDate((STF_GRP_TLY.START_MOMENT-240)/1440)) < CDate((STF_GRP_TLY.STOP_MOMENT-240)/1440)
```

although I would be inclined to create a saved query that does the conversion to real date/time values ...

[qryIntervals]

```sql
SELECT 
    STF_GRP_SK, 
    CDate((START_MOMENT-240)/1440) AS START, 
    CDate((STOP_MOMENT-240)/1440) AS END, 
    TLY 
FROM STF_GRP_TLY
```

... and then use it in the following simplified query to generate the sub-intervals

```sql
SELECT 
    qryIntervals.STF_GRP_SK, 
    DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, qryIntervals.START) AS dtmSTART, 
    DateAdd("n", 30 * (tblNumbers.n + 1), qryIntervals.START) AS dtmEND, 
    qryIntervals.TLY 
FROM qryIntervals, tblNumbers 
WHERE 
    DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, qryIntervals.START) < qryIntervals.END
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help here!  I'm having some difficulty putting it all together unfortunately and was wondering if you could me a step further!  When I simply what I have (Updated my original coding above to help) I am getting a 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression' error.  Is it possible it may be related to the date format I'm using?  The date is stored in nominal format and I'm converting (e.g. 61275180/1440 = 42552.20833 = 7/1/2016 05:00)

Comment: You could create a saved query in Access that converts the "nominal" dates to real date/time values, e.g. `SELECT ... CDate((SGT.STOP_MOMENT-240)/1440) AS END, ...` and then use that saved query just like you would use a table when creating your subsequent queries.

Comment: Unfortunately no go, tried the below with no success.  I do appreciate the try :)

    SELECT
      tblIntervals.STF_GRP_SK, DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, CVDate(tblIntervals.START_MOMENT-240)/1440) AS dtmSTART,
      DateAdd("n", 30 * (tblNumbers.n + 1), CVDate(tblIntervals.START_MOMENT-240)/1440) AS dtmEND,
      tblIntervals.TLY
    FROM
      STF_GRP_TLY AS tblIntervals, tblNumbers
    WHERE
    DateAdd("n", 30 * tblNumbers.n, CVDate(tblIntervals.START_MOMENT-240)/1440) < CVDate(tblIntervals.STOP_MOMENT-240)/1440;

Comment: You are missing some parentheses. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Gord, I REALLY appreciate you taking the time to help out!  I hate to be someone who needed to be spoon fed, but you've been extremely helpful, so thank you!  I've done as you suggested including making the doing a query for the date/time conversion and it works!  (Sort of)  In stances where START/END are = 90 minutes or greater it shows some odd behaviour.   I'll play a bit to see what I can come up with.  Thank you again!  *Edit 60 to 90 minutes)